# Html wrap div full width

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page with a div containing another div that contains all users in a database (chat system) however the ul li tag is not taking the full width of the parent div. This is an image of the expected outcome: http://prntscr.com/nz6byp

I already tried setting the width to 100%.

HTML

```
.left-sidebar{ 
    background-color:#F7F7F7; 
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}


.searchbox{ 
    padding:20px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-group-btn{
    margin: auto;
}

.search-icon{
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-size: 250%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #77A1D3 0%, #79CBCA 51%, #77A1D3 100%);
    transition: background 0.5s ease-out;
    color:#fff;
} 

.search-icon:hover{
    background-position: right center;
    color: #fff;  
} 

.form-control:focus{ 
    border:2px solid #fff; 
} 

.chat-left-img,.chat-left-detail{ 
    float: left; 
} 



.left-chat{ 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
} 


.left-chat::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
}

.left-chat::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.left-chat::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);*/
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
}


.left-chat ul{ 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0px;

} 


.left-chat ul li{ 
    list-style: none; 
    width:100%; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 0px;
    transition: background 0.25s ease-out;
}

.left-chat ul li:hover{ 
    background-color: #E2E2E2
}

.chat-left-img img{ 
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    text-align: left; 
    float:fixed; 
    padding: 3px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #77A1D3 0%, #79CBCA 51%, #77A1D3 100%);
    background-size: 250%;
} 


.chat-left-details{ 
    width: 100%;
} 

.chat-left-details a{
    margin: 5%; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5D5C5C;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.online{ 
    margin: 5%; 
    color:#86BB71;
    font-size: 14px;
} 

.offline{ 
    margin: 5%; 
    color:#C6C4C4;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-cs-12 left-sidebar">
    <div class="input-group searchbox">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
            <center><a href="find_friends.php"><button id="" class="btn btn-default search-icon" name="search_user" type="submit">Add new user</button></a></center>
       </div>                    
    </div> 
    <div class="left-chat">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <div class='chat-left-img'> <img src='$user_profilepic'>
               </div>
               <div class='chat-left-details'>
                   <a href='home.php?user_name=$user_name'>$user_name</a> 
                   <span style='font-size: 12px; color: #5D5C5C;'>(You) 
                   </span><br>
               </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide HTML and CSS with working example..

Comment: Replace the PHP include with `li` items

Comment: Done, any feedback now please?

Comment: #christianilvi the problem is not with ul and li, or even the .left-chat element. their width are 100% and they are ok. (as you can see here: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/KLOmYG) the problem is with parent of .left-chat element, wich you don't include in the html/css.

Comment: @christianilvi please include parent element of left char as well.

Comment: @yayapro https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQgzKG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list elements' width is set to 100% of container, but container has padding, thats why you think it's not filled the container.

`.left-sidebar` has `padding: 20px;`, and also `.left-chat` has `overflow-y: scroll`. these two rules makes element smaller than you expect (some for parent padding, some for scrollbar width).

you can `padding: 0` for `.left-sidebar` and set `overflow-y: auto` for `.left-chat`.

Also you can inspect elements on chrome dev tools, to see whats going on.

you can see this here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/qGejrq)

Comment: @christianilvi you meant this? (codepen added also to answer)

Comment: @christianilvi no problem. glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your .left-sidebar has a 20px padding.
I removed left and right padding and now the list take full width

```
.left-sidebar{ 
    background-color:#F7F7F7; 
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

```css
.left-sidebar{ 
    background-color:#F7F7F7; 
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}


.searchbox{ 
    padding:20px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-group-btn{
    margin: auto;
}

.search-icon{
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-size: 250%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #77A1D3 0%, #79CBCA 51%, #77A1D3 100%);
    transition: background 0.5s ease-out;
    color:#fff;
} 

.search-icon:hover{
    background-position: right center;
    color: #fff;  
} 

.form-control:focus{ 
    border:2px solid #fff; 
} 

.chat-left-img,.chat-left-detail{ 
    float: left; 
} 



.left-chat{ 
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
} 

.left-chat::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.left-chat::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);*/
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

.left-chat ul{ 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0px;

} 

.left-chat ul li{ 
    list-style: none; 
    width:100%; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 0px;
    transition: background 0.25s ease-out;
}

.left-chat ul li:hover{ 
    background-color: #E2E2E2
}

.chat-left-img img{ 
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    text-align: left; 
    float:fixed; 
    padding: 3px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #77A1D3 0%, #79CBCA 51%, #77A1D3 100%);
    background-size: 250%;
} 

.chat-left-details{ 
    width: 100%;
} 

.chat-left-details a{
    margin: 5%; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5D5C5C;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-cs-12 left-sidebar">
    <div class="input-group searchbox">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
            <center><a href="find_friends.php"><button id="" class="btn btn-default search-icon" name="search_user" type="submit">Add new user</button></a></center>
       </div>                    
    </div> 
    <div class="left-chat">
       <ul class="full-width-no-padding">
           <li class="full-width-no-padding">
               <div class='chat-left-img'> <img src='$user_profilepic'>
               </div>
               <div class='chat-left-details'>
                   <a href='home.php?user_name=$user_name'>$user_name</a> 
                   <span style='font-size: 12px; color: #5D5C5C;'>(You) 
                   </span><br>
               </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

**EDIT**

As @yaya pro suggested i added `overflow-y: auto;` to `.left-chat` class